# How do you add the second reference?

Tags: cross-referencing, back-referencing

I have and it works

```
@misc{GDP:2012,
ALTauthor = {The World Bank},
ALTeditor = {},
title = {GDP Per Capita (Current \$US)},
year = {2012},
url = {http://data.worldbank.org/indicator/NY.GDP.PCAP.CD},
}
```

and I have tried to add the second reference after it like here:

```
@misc{GDP:2012,
ALTauthor = {The World Bank},
ALTeditor = {},
title = {GDP Per Capita (Current \$US)},
year = {2012},
url = {http://data.worldbank.org/indicator/NY.GDP.PCAP.CD},
}


{GDP:2013,
ALTauthor = {The World Bank3},
ALTeditor = {Sexolopianos},
title = {GDP Per Capita (Current \$US)},
year = {2013},
url = {http://data.worldbank.org/iffdicator/NY.GDP.PCAP.CD},
}
```

But it didn't work. What should one do to add the second source in order to make it work.

Comment: You need to specify the type of reference for the second one too. I gather it's the same type as the first, so it should read: `@misc{GDP:2013,`.

Comment: You forgot the type `@misc` (or any type that best matches this kind of publication).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is could be considered too-localized. That is, it is a very particular problem that may not benefit the larger community of (future) visitors to the site.